# CKAN not starting from Docker Desktop

Tags: ckan

I am trying to deploy CKAN from Docker (using Docker Desktop).  I run the docker setup file and all the containers get created (ckan, solr, redis, datapusher and db).  All the containers are able to startup except for CKAN.  When I look in the containers logs, I see this error:

> exec /ckan-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

I've tried restarting the container but it does not fix the issue.  My details:

Windows 10, running Docker Desktop, using Ubuntu-22.04 for WSL.  I am pulling the docker install file from : https://github.com/ckan/ckan.git.  I have also tried changing branches to ckan-2.9.5.

I am really stumped on how to get CKAN running.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you do `ls -l /ckan-entrypoint.sh`, what is the output?

Comment: I am new to docker.  So, correct me if I am doing this wrong.  I can see that the ckan-entrypoint.sh file is located in ckan\contrib\docker folder.  So, in powershell, I go to that foler and run your command.  I get this error:  ls : Cannot find path 'C:\ckan-entrypoint.sh' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ ls -l /ckan-entrypoint.sh

Comment: Does this mean it expects to finds that file in the root of C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that ckan-entrypoint.sh is expected to have an EOL formatted for Linux.  Because I was on Windows, the end of line format was not recognized.  When I formatted the file for Linux, it worked.